# Operate loss with respect to every single datapoint in batch

Tags: pytorch

When using a 64 size batch, I need to fine-operate the loss value with respect to every single data point.
I know I can use `reduction='none'` when creating a loss function object then I can get a fine granularity loss value. But it's better to be a regular loss object without setting `reduction='none'`, to keep consistency with other code.

It there any way to operate finer loss value without `reduction='none'`?

Comment: *"better be a regular loss object without setting "reduction='none'""*, why so?

Comment: We are organizing our work as a package. Basically our method assigns every datapoint's loss value different weights then backpropagate, when people use it, we better don't expect they pre-initialize a loss with specific argument, to make the package non-invasive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you wrap the function with your predefined options?

```
def custom_loss(*args, **kwargs):
    return some_builtin(*args, **kwargs, reduction='none')
```

Where `some_builtin` would be a builtin PyTorch loss, *e.g.* `torch.functional.l1_loss`, `torch.functional.mse_loss`, ...